# multiple CASE when statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

are these two statement equivalent in snowflake.

Case 1:

```
CASE  
  when VAL='ABC' then 'ALPHA' 
  when VAL='123' then 'NUMERIC'
  else  'ALPHANUMERIC'
  end;
```

Case 2:

```
VOBJECTDESCRIPTION = 

CASE WHEN VAL='ABC'  THEN 'ALPHA' ELSE
  CASE WHEN VAL='123'  THEN 'ALPHA' ELSE   
  'ALPHANUMERIC' 
  END END;
```

Comment: You can indent code with 4 spaces in Stackoverflow's implentation of markdown and it will preserve line feeds and spacing (also highlighting the code and pressing the `{}` in the editor will work too). I made an attempt to edit your question so it's readable. Feel free to edit more if I misunderstood.

Comment: As for your question, they only appear to be different syntactically, but should have the same output (ignoring the `VOBJECTDESCRIPTION=` on the second example.

Comment: The second one is technically syntactically wrong, but that's just because you're using double quotes around `ALPHANUMERIC`, which makes Snowflake treat that as a column name rather than a string literal.

Comment: thanks for the answer .Thanks for the formatting and tips. will remember it.

Comment: @shivanibist: If you feel your question was answered, please mark the answer so other users know you don't still need help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've got several typos which make these both different, but given the gist of what you're trying to ask: statements like these both have the same behavior.

```
WITH X as (
    select VAL from (values ('1'), ('2'), ('ABC')) as x(VAL)
)
SELECT CASE  
  when VAL='ABC' then 'ALPHA' 
  when VAL='123' then 'NUMERIC'
  else 'ALPHANUMERIC'
  end
FROM X;
```

```
WITH X as (
    select VAL from (values ('1'), ('2'), ('ABC')) as x(VAL)
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN VAL='ABC' THEN 'ALPHA' 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN VAL='123' THEN 'NUMERIC'
        ELSE 'ALPHANUMERIC'
        END
    END
FROM X;
```

From the parser's perspective, the first option thinks of all the `WHEN`s as siblings, whereas the second one treats the entire second `CASE` statement as a child of the first `ELSE`. But I doubt there'd be any measurable difference in performance.

The first syntax is simpler, and I would favor it for readability. Even better, you can do this to avoid duplicative `VAL=` syntax:

```
WITH X as (
    select VAL from (values ('1'), ('2'), ('ABC')) as x(VAL)
)
SELECT CASE VAL
  when 'ABC' then 'ALPHA' 
  when '123' then 'NUMERIC'
  else 'ALPHANUMERIC'
  end
FROM X;
```